# How to pass a parameter by variable into data.table[J()]

Tags: r, optimization, data.table

I'm brand new to the (completely marvelous) `data.table` package, and seem to have gotten stuck on a very basic, somewhat bizarre problem. I can't post the exact data set I'm working with, for which I apologize -- but I think the problem is simple enough to articulate that hopefully this will still be very clear.

Let's say I have a data.table like so, with key x:

```
set1
   x y
1: 1 a
2: 1 b
3: 1 c
4: 2 a
```

I want to return a subset of `set1` containing all rows where `x == 1`. This is wonderfully simple in data.table: `set1[J(1)]`. Bam. Done. I can also assign `z <- 1`, and call `set1[J(z)]`. Again: works great.

...except when I try to scale it up to my actual data set, which contains ~6M rows. When I call `set1[J(1674)]`, I get back a 78-row return that's exactly what I'm looking for. But I need to be able to look up (literally) 4M of these subsets. When I assign the value I'm searching for to a variable, `id <- 1674`, and call `set1[J(id)]`... R nearly takes down my desktop.

Clearly *something* I don't understand is going on under the data.table hood, but I haven't been able to figure out what. Googling and slogging through Stack Overflow suggest that this should work. Out of pure whimsey, I've tried:

```
id <- quote(1674)
set1[J(eval(id))]
```

...but that is far, far worse. What... what's going on?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on what R is printing out?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, I can provide more detail -- but R isn't printing out *anything*. According to `top`, when I call `set1[J(id)]`, rsession starts using up to 97% of system memory. The box becomes functionally unusable until I manage to kill the rsession process some time later. This is by contrast to `set1[J(1674)]`, which returns 78 rows as soon as I press `enter`.

Comment: Is id a column in your data.table set1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ @mnel beat me to it as I was writing ...]

Almost certainly, one column of `set1` happens to be called `"id"`; i.e.,

```
isTRUE("id" %in% names(set1))
```

causing `set1[J(id)]` to self join `set1$id` to `set1`, ignoring the `id` in calling scope.

If so, there are several approaches to avoid scoping issues such as this :

```
.id = <your 4M ids>
set1[J(.id)]
```

or use the fact that a single name `i` is evaluated in calling scope :

```
JDT=J(id); set1[JDT]
```

or that `eval` is `eval`'d in calling scope, too :

```
set1[eval(J(id))]
```

or, we do want to make this clearer, more robust and easier, so one thought is to add `..` :

```
set1[..(J(id))]     # .. alias for eval
```

or perhaps :

```
set1[J(..id)]
```

where `..` borrows its meaning from the file system's `..`, meaning one-level-up.  If the `..` was a prefix to symbols, you could then do something like :

```
DT[colB==..id]
```

where `==` is used there for illustration. In that example `colB` is expected to be a column name and `..id` will find `id` in calling scope (one level up). The thinking is that that would be quite clear to the reader of the code what the programmer intended.

Comment: Ha! Yeah, that's exactly it. Thanks very much! Blast it, in retrospect that seems screechingly obvious.